# Ionic 6 cordova platform problem with angular 14

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I got the error when i was running the app on the browser .

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

The error was

```
Error: Unknown argument: platform [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.   ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser exited with exit code 1. Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

My Configs

> Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.0.5
@angular/cli                  : 14.0.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : browser 6.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : 1.6.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v16.16.0
npm               : 8.2.0
OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution the thing which i was missing was

```
ng add @ionic/cordova-builders
```

It is a collection of builders for @ionic/angular projects using Cordova.

This solution also works for **android** and **ios**

Answer (score 0):

This error happen beacause you don't did the migration of an application in Angular to Ionic, the solution is simple.

Run

```
npm install @ionic/angular@6
```

If you are using Ionic Angular Server, be sure to update that as well:

```
npm install @ionic/angular@6 @ionic/angular-server@6
```

However if that's code don't run try this code:

```
npm install @ionic/angular@latest @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save
```

if need read the documentation of the migration:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration

I hope than help you

Comment: The problem was with the cordova platforms even i updated the angular to the required version but the problem still existed at that time .

Comment: @MuhammadAli could you describe how you solved this problem, please? I spent whole day to figure out what's going on...